# Nesting fgets with stdin

Tags: c

I am trying to loop through every line in a file and every line in stdin to make a comparison. When I nest fgets in while loops the outer loop does not go though a second time. I've seen that if the inner loop was a file it could be closed to reset to the first line, but I can't seem to do the same thing with stdin. Is there a way to restart at the beginning of stdin?

```
while (fgets(fline, sizeof(fline), fileInput)){
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)){
        printf("%s", fline);
        printf("%s", line); 
    }
    fclose(fileInput);
}
```

if file input contained

```
a
b
c
```

and std in was

```
d
e
```

I want it to print

```
a
d
a
e
b
d
b
e
c
d
c
e
```

Comment: if `stdin` is pointed to the keyboard rather than a file, then there is no way to backup, as the keyboard cannot be backed up.  However, if `stdin` is pointed to a file, then can backup in the file, using something like `fseek()`

Answer (score 3):

After the inner loop completes, you've reached the end of `stdin`. So when you go to the next iteration of the outer loop, there's nothing left in `stdin`, so the inner loop ends immediately.

Assuming `stdin` is connected to a seekable stream (e.g. an ordinary file), you can solve this by rewinding back to the beginning before the inner loop.

Another problem was that you were closing `fileInput` inside the loop. So after you read the first line of that file, it was closing the file, so it got an error trying to read the next line.

```
while (fgets(fline, sizeof(fline), fileInput)){
    rewind(stdin);
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)){
        printf("%s", fline);
        printf("%s", line); 
    }
}
fclose(fileInput);
```

A more general solution would be to read `stdin` into an array, then iterate over the array instead of using a `fgets` loop.